# Appending dict to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

new to python.
I am reading rows from the origin dataframe and trying to append it to target dataframe. 
here is my program
main code to read each row of rawdata.

```
for i,row in raw_data.iterrows():
    tool=row['entity']
    shift=row['shift_info']
    time=row['time_delta']
    set_flag (tool,shift,time,raw_data,Display_data)
```

then i construct a dict to append to target dataframe.

```
def set_flag(tool,shift,time,raw_data,Display_data):
    for j,rows in Display_data.iterrows(): 

        temp_col='time'+str(time)
        if(rows['entity']==tool and rows['shift_info']==shift):
            rows[temp_col]=1
        else:
         #   print tool                          
            newrow = [{'shift_info':shift,'entity':tool,temp_col:1}]  
         #  print newrow
            Display_data = Display_data.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)
```

the code executes, but the Display_data dataframe is not changed. 
any one can educate me my problem? thank you!

Comment: As an intial comment, iterating over an object and then modifying it inside the loop is inherently dangerous and likely to yield unexpected/undefined results. What happens if you just append to a list and then append to the dataframe outside of the for loop?

Comment: Please never change object on which you are looping. Always create copy of it and change it. Your code is like `cutting same branch on which you are sitting`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import copy

def set_flag(tool,shift,time,raw_data,Display_data):
    new_data = copy.deepcopy(Display_data)
    for j,rows in Display_data.iterrows(): 
        temp_col='time'+str(time)
        if(rows['entity']==tool and rows['shift_info']==shift):
            rows[temp_col]=1
        else:
         #   print tool                          
            newrow = [{'shift_info':shift,'entity':tool,temp_col:1}]  
         #  print newrow
            new_data.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)
    return new_data
```

Get new variable where you are calling.

```
Display_data = set_flag (tool,shift,time,raw_data,Display_data)
```

Comment: Just as a pandas-specific tip, DataFrames have a `copy` method that defaults to performing a deep copy.